# Can I modify data by using SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a few programs written with Access 2007. There are some forms where people change data and it saves the data into a database.
Can I implement the same functionality of the forms from Access 2007 with SQL Server Reporting Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS is a reporting platform and is not intended as a CRUD platform. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587193/ssrs-call-stored-procedure-using-reportitems-textbox-maybe-custom-report-code) before you start.

If you want to do it anyway, you should add a Stored Procedure as first Report Dataset as explained [here](http://www.advancedssrs.com/2014/01/how-can-i-run-stored-procedures-with.html). I've used this approach but just to mark some selected records as deleted not to do complex funcionality.