# Calculate a column from a table depending on different column from another tablecomputed column based on different

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have tables:

```
create table Aprovizionari
(
  ID_Aprovizionare  int     identity(1,1) primary key, 
  CodCarte          char(3) foreign key references Carti(CodCarte),
  CodLibrarie       char(3) foreign key references Librarii(CodLibrarie),
  DataAprovizionare date    default getdate(), 
  Cantitate         int     default 1 
)
create table Returnari
(
 CodRet char(3) primary key,
 CodCarte char(3) foreign key references Carti(CodCarte),
 CodLibrarie char(3) foreign key references Librarii(CodLibrarie),
 CodEditura char(4) foreign key references Edituri(CodEditura),
 DataRet date,
 Cantitate int
)
```

I have a trigger that decrement the column Cantitate(Quantity) from Aprovizionari(Supply) while I add in Cantitate from another table Facturi(Invoices).

In Returnari(Returns -of books) I should have:

```
DataRet date,--this should be =DataAprovizionare+3 mounths
Cantitate int--this should be=the remaining Cantitate(Quantity) from Aprovizionari at date=DataAprovizionare+3 mounts
```

Comment: Is the idea that a `Returnari` record is automatically created 3 months after the `Aprovizionari` record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you're going to need to check every day for `Aprovizionari` records that are 3 months old. When you find one you'll `INSERT` the `Returnari` record.

To do this you've got to create a stored procedure that when executed will create the `Returnari` records and then schedule a SQL Server Agent job to execute the procedure every day.

The stored procedure will look something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourDailyProc ( @Date DATE )
AS
    INSERT INTO Returnari (CodCarte, CodLibrarie, DataRet, Cantitate)
    SELECT CodCarte, CobLibrarie, CAST(@Date AS DATE), Cantitate
    FROM Aprovizionari 
    WHERE DataAprovizionare = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @Date) AS DATE)
GO
```

It's not clear where you'd get `CodEditura` but presumably you just need to join to another table.

Now you need a job to execute `EXEC YourDailyProc @Date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` each day. This answer looks like it has all the information you'll need to do that - [how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471440/2742805)