# Executing particular query at regular intervals in mssql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, scheduler, executequery

I need to execute a query at regular intervals in my server. The query is to select a particular date from a table in my database, check it with the current date, and if current date is higher then do some particular tasks like inserting values to another table. If current date is lower than the selected date value then do nothing. How can this be achieved? Is there any possible way of doing this using trigger or by using cron jobs. My server is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3393.0 (X64). I have done the server side code for my android application in C#.net. I'm new to the world of C#.net and SQL queries. Can someone please help me out in this matter.

Comment: This has been previously answered here: [how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with SQL server agent, more details can be found in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx