# Event scheduler using aspx

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, events, scheduler

In php I can make events using phpmyadmin and just type:

```
CREATE EVENT x ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2011-12-01 20:00:00' DO UPDATE users_table SET x = x +3;
```

(this event updates the database every 24 hours and increase the x of every user by 3)

But I dont know how to do this (and where) in aspx (visual studio).

Please help me :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily

Comment: I cant find the "SQL Server Agent" node and the "Jobs" node.