# Send automatically mail to users in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to send automatic email to user after expiration period of their plan.All users will have a different expiration time.IS there any other way instead of using workflow,and if only way is workflow then how to do it with workflow. Please give me a direction .

> I am working on ASP.NET web site.(VS2010)
>   All user may have different expiration time like 1 month , 2 month etc
>   So it is a long running task or process for web application.
>   I can create workflow (console application in vs2010) but dont have any idea how to it with asp.net website.

Comment: Just do a check on a request basis, no need to have a separate system. Unless you have no users, but then you no-one would care ;p

Comment: (System should be automatic!)I have users in my system .situation is like this: A user registered for a service for a specific time period .After that period over that user should receive a email about service expiration!

Comment: you can Use windows service or windows scheduler for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try **windows service** if you can install it on your production server or use **MSSQL schedule job** to achieve this task.

**For windows service:**

[Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

[Schedule Email Through ASP.NET or Schedule Tasks Using ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49996/Schedule-Email-Through-ASP-NET-or-Schedule-Tasks-U)

[Scheduling Window Service Daily,Weekly,Monthly](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/350635/Scheduling-Window-Service-Daily-Weekly-Monthly)

**For MSSQL Schedule job:**

[how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

[Automated Email Notifications using SQL Server Job Schedular](http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/automated-email-notifications-using-sql-server-job-schedular.aspx)

Comment: ill go with second option of schedule sql script or job on db server. But can give me any idea how can i schedule daily job on  db server ,like on godaddy MSSQL db  how can i schedule the jobs ?

Comment: you need assistance from your hosting server technical support for the same