# SQL-Server generate data row once per day

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm quite a newbie to the topic databases. It may be that the topic 
already exists, but I don't even know how to search for it.
How to query and so on seems to be no problem.
And how to write a trigger on an INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE statement is known too.

I would like to know if it is possible to execute some code to generate a data row 
every day once at a specific time without an external programm.

Thanks, Chris

PS: I'm from Germany, so don't get angry about my expressions, please^^

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily

Comment: Well, I guess I will mark the question as answered. Thanks for the clear answer. 
I seem to have the Express Version which does not have the server agent, because I'm logged on as 'sa' at the database engine and I can't see the node for it. So I will try for the version with the Windows scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not in an `Express Edition` you may create an SQL Job to do that.

- Open SSMS
- Drill Down your server instance
- Drill Down `SQL Server Agent`
- Right click `Jobs` folder
- Chose `New Job`
- Fill in the details in the `General Tab`
- Go to the `Steps` tab
- Click `New`
- Enter a name, choose which db to run against and enter your SQL statement.
- Go to `Schedules` tab
- Add a schedule to run once each day at the time you wish.

Comment: why -1? One can argue how smart it is to use this part - the agent -for this, but it is a correct answer. Express does not have the agent, so there is no scheduler. Hardly the fault of the poster of the answer.

Comment: @TomTom Thanks for the support. Not to mention that i did note myself that it would not work on the Express edition.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that this "not in express edition" was not snippy from you. I prefer not to use the agent for an in application thing, but the answer IS correct.

Comment: @TomTom Well, in my mind a thing that happens at a specific time each day and it is marked as a db issue (not a mention to a client application) seems that it must be done with a scheduler, sql or windows.

Comment: Absolutely, I just keep them out of SQL Server. Mostly to do with "I dont want the hassle of tracking what jobs run" while a scheduler on the application server can be installed with the msi file. I use the agent only for server level administrative tasks (check, backup etc.). Makes a clear responsibility separation.