# How do I update the column value after 4 days?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, job-scheduling

I am looking for your assistant in understanding the way and the code to get the column value to be changed after 4 days.

Currently, whenever I am inserting a new row in the database, the value of the flag will be "Y" by default and I will capture the created date & time by storing the sysdate by default. Now, I want the flag to be changed to "N" after 4 days from the creation.

So, please guide and instruct me on the way to do the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into creating a Trigger on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE **IF** your table is frequently accessed for those operations.

If not, then you would have to schedule a job to run SQL daily or how frequent you'd like to check.

[how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Comment: Do you know how to do this in toad?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. The job will check the no. of days and I should run a trigger to update the flag?

Comment: @user3407440 you don't need a trigger if you have a job running. http://bloggingaboutoracle.com/creating-jobs-in-toad-for-oracle/

Comment: And where should I check the 4 days?

Comment: @user3407440 just add a simple update statement. 'UPDATE SET valueFlag = Y WHERE DATEDIFF(day,[date_column],GETDATE()) > 4'