# Why can't I add SQLUserAgentRole to "sa" user on msdb?

Tags: sql-server, user-roles, sql-job, sql-server-2014-express

I'm trying to schedule an sql query to run daily. For that I need (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)) to use a user with the SQLUserAgentRole database role.

So I've tried to add the SQLUserAgentRole to the "sa" user on the msdb database but I get the error 15405: Cannot use the special principal 'dbo'.

[image: error print]

What am I missing?

Comment: The `sa` account can already do *everything* on the server. It does not *need* any additional permissions (and you can't give it any) because what would that even mean?

Comment: @Tanner Why can't I see the SQL Server Agent node in object explorer then?

Comment: "Why can't I see the SQL Server Agent node" - at a wild guess, because you're connected to a SQL Server *Express* instance. Express doesn't support agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get this error message if you try to add the login that is mapped to the user 'dbo' in the database to *any* database role. For example:

```
alter role [db_datareader] add member [dbo];
```

Gives the same error message. Why it's an error, I cannot say. But as others have implied above, sa can already do everything on the server level which includes all database level permissions as well.