# Run daily report for yesterday

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to nightly run a report at 1am for all the customers who visited the hotel yesterday. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. I am trying as below but it doesn't give me any records. CheckInDate format is '2015-09-02 06:45:00.000'. Please assist. Thanks.

```
Select top 5 * from Customers where CheckInDate =  DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Below worked:

```
select top 5 * from Customers where cast(CheckInDate as date) = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()-1), MONTH(GETDATE()-1), DAY(GETDATE()-1))
```

Comment: You have hh:mm:ss part which may vary, convert both to DATE or use `BETWEEN  date 00:00:00 AND date date 23:59:59`

Comment: where `DATE(CheckInDate)=..`Also TOP needs an ORDER BY

Comment: I did Select top 5 * from Customers where cast(CheckInDate as date) =  DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())....still no results.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT top 5 from Customers where CheckInDate = DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,'2015-09-02 06:45:00.000'),0) - 1
```

The `DateAdd` function will convert the date into `2015-09-02 00:00:00.000` format and you subtract minus 1 day. i.e. `2015-09-01 00:00:00.000`

you can pass the date in stored procedure as parameter and the rest will be taken care by the select statement

hope this helps..

Comment: I tried datefromparts and it worked. I updated the solution in my original question. The report needs to auto run at night so I can't use any manual date as '2015-09-02 06:45:00.000'.

Comment: Create and schedule a job in Sql Server . I would prefer writing a stored procedure, you can write the sql query also

Comment: here's the link from stackoverflow for scheduling a jon in sql server to run daily.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 * from Customers where cast(CheckInDate as date) = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()-1), MONTH(GETDATE()-1), DAY(GETDATE()-1))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Is your yesterday a TranDate - 1? Maybe this should help.

```
select top 5 * from customers where checkindate 
BETWEEN
        CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(GETDATE() - 1),101) + ' 00:00') -- start of the day or you can modify it base on your report cut-off
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(GETDATE() - 1),101) + ' 23:59') -- until end of the day or '23:59' of the GETDATE() - 1
```

what this does is

`(GETDATE() - 1),101)` = '09/03/2015'
then ' 00:00' then gives you '09/03/2015 00:00:00' then convert this to datetime again as filter

hopefully this helps.