# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have generated a script by right-clicking on `DB -> Tasks -> Generate Script`.

I was able to use it to back up the 5 tables I wanted to a `.sql` file that I use to import those 5 tables to a different server. How do I get to run that script I made every night?

It has to be setup to where it backups to a file that I can import. I can not setup Master-> slave..

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Comment: I do not know how to write the T-SQL .. to back those tables up. I get to the step where I am suppose to write the T- SQL Script but I do not know what to put. I have the tables name.

Comment: Have you looked into powershell SMO object? Looks like a good candidate.

Comment: I have not looked into SMO, I am new to SQL. I do not know how to write the T-SQL to dump 5 tables and its data