# How to update a row values at a specific time in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to change a row's values when a specific time happens in SQL Server

```
customerId  isBlock       time
-------------------------------  
1           false         12:00
```

When the time 12:00 happens, dynamically will change `isBlock` value to `true`

Comment: Is `time` the current time (i.e. at 12:00 PM every day, change the value of the column), or a column within the table (when the value is 12:00 PM, `isBlock` must be set to true)?

Comment: everyday when it passes 12:00 PM , change value to true

Comment: You probably want some sort of a scheduled job then - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily) for how to do it as a SQL Job.

Comment: There are two way to do this: One is creating a service continuously running in background that awakes roughly at the 12 o'clock and works on your db. The other one is throuth the [Sql Server Agent service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(v=sql.105).aspx) creating the appropriate job and execute a stored procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to use a computed column (or view).  So:

```
alter table t
    add column isBlock (case when getdate() > time then 'true' else 'false' end);
```

Notes:

- The original column is not needed for this logic.
- I am assuming that "time" is really some sort of date/time value, so the comparison to `getdate()` is appropriate.