# Creating a new table in the same style daily/weekly mssql

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of data that I want to insert into a database daily, creating a new table every day or every week to have an easy historic overview.

How can I accomplish that? Should I do it in code or in the database itself?

Comment: please add some sample data and expected output

Comment: Expecting on daily basis on a particular time? or when ever you need, that time only the data need to move into the new table?

Comment: You can achieve this by the [SQL Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Comment: @Arulkumar Daily/weekly basis on specific time.

Comment: Actually, it's not a very good idea for multiple reasons. If you decide to go this route anyway, pls make sure to add a check constraint to the date column. See "partitioned view" (eg here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information on this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `MySourceTable` is your actual table, from there you want to move the data on daily basis, you need to create a SQL Job and use the below SP.

So you will get a daily based table with the prefix name you provide. For testing I give here `MyTest_` as prefix, so today's table will come as `MyTest_2016_04_15`.

Sample Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pub_DailyBasisDataMove
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @LogDate VARCHAR(20);
    SET @LogDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 111), '/', '_');
    -- PRINT @LogDate

    DECLARE @ExecuteSql AS NVARCHAR (MAX) = '';
    SET @ExecuteSql = @ExecuteSql + N'SELECT * INTO MyTest_' + @LogDate + ' FROM dbo.MySourceTable'
    --PRINT @ExecuteSql

    EXEC sp_executesql @ExecuteSql

END
```

Note: If you want to run the job more than once in day, you need to Drop the existing table for the day and create the new.

In the same way you need to create one more SP for weekly basis and separate JOB and handle the same in the prefix content inside the SP.