# How to run a stored procedure automatically every day in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks, sql-server-2016

I am wondering about how to accomplish this. I want to run a certain stored procedure every day automatically. How is that done? I did find a few answers but this software I am running is Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Has anyone done this successfully in the 2016 version of the software? Thanks

Comment: You're looking for the [SQL Server Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx), which is part of SQL Server. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) will walk you through setting up a job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Comment: Looks like I dont have proper security to access the agent which is found in config manager.  Is this process done by code in the 2016 version now or is it a security issue that my boss has to give me?

Comment: You shouldn't need access to the configuration manager; try accessing it through Management Studio by expanding the 'SQL Server Agent' node underneath the server name in Object Explorer.

Comment: I look all over and I didnt find SQL Server Agent under the server name.  Is it accessible anywhere else?

Comment: If you've checked in Object Explorer and you don't see an image similar to [this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_ZEcKubITMq_y-tbnVbgpnqUNiJCJeJAW0JiyEKNbrcyUV2u_BQ), then yes you need some better permissions.  I'd recommend asking for membership in the `SQLAgentOperatorRole`, per [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you, for now my boss and I are going to run it manually every morning.  Eventually we will get to do the permissions thing.  Thank you everyone.