# How to automatically trigger a query at specific time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, scheduled-tasks

How can I run this query using auto trigger 5 minutes before the time of next prayer?

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(minute, -5, (SELECT TOP 1 TIME 
                         FROM prayertimes 
                         WHERE Time > sysdatetime())) AS TIME
```

Here are details of the `prayertimes` table:

```
Id  P_id  TIME
---------------------------------
698  3    2016-10-08 15:31:00.000
699  4    2016-10-08 18:02:00.000
700  5    2016-10-08 19:32:00.000
701  1    2016-10-09 04:59:00.000
702  2    2016-10-09 12:08:00.000
703  3    2016-10-09 15:30:00.000
704  4    2016-10-09 18:02:00.000
705  5    2016-10-09 19:32:00.000
```

Let us say that next datetime is `2016-10-08 15:31:00.000`.

Then I want to trigger the query automatically at `2016-10-08 15:26:00.000`.

Any stored procedure?

Thanks

Comment: Is this what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily

Comment: Neither Windows nor SQL Server are particularly adept at running tasks at a specific millisecond. Then there are time changes, e.g. clock synchronization with trusted sources and DST, that may confuse the issue. Is forgiveness available?

Comment: Even i don't need milliseconds. I just need to Trigger it on specific Minutes only like `2016-10-08 15:26:00.000`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way with job:

1. Put your query into stored procedure,
2. Create a job that will check interval `DATEDIFF(minute,GETDATE(),<next pray time>)` every minute (or 30 seconds),
3. If interval is <= 5 minutes it will launch stored procedure execution.

The way with trigger and job.

1. Create a trigger on update, insert, delete to keep schedule updated,
2. Create a job that will launch your query,
3. Trigger you create on first step will create a schedule for this job,
4. If some changes is done to table, trigger should update the job schedule.