# tsql runs fine in MSSM but failes when I put it into a job

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I have a small script that I use to rebuild indexes and update statistics on a SQL Server 2014 database.
It runs fine when I execute it in MSSM so I wanted to put it into a job to run every night.

I used this link to create the job :
    [how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

and this is my script in step 1:

```
declare @command nvarchar(1000) 
DECLARE @TableName varchar(255) 
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR  
  SELECT table_name 
  FROM   information_schema.tables 
  WHERE  table_type = 'base table' 

OPEN TableCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
  set @command = 'alter index all on ' + @TableName + ' rebuild'
  exec sp_executesql @command
  set @command = 'update statistics ' + @TableName
  exec sp_executesql @command

  FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName 
END 
CLOSE TableCursor 
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

and this is my script in step 2:

```
insert into tblLog values (getdate(), 0, 'sql agent job rebuild index', 'indexes rebuild')
```

When I try `Start Job at Step` it failes however with this message in the history for step 1:

> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$GTT_192. ALTER INDEX failed
>   because the following SET options have incorrect settings:
>   'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with
>   indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1934).  The step
>   failed.

I have no clue where this setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER comes from.

So why does it works when I run it in MSSM and not in a job ?
And more important, what can I do to get it working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add in script at the begining:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```