# How to schedule a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, and I want to delete rows daily for more than 30 days.

Which means, everyday a bit of data is saved (new record) in database, and **the first day data will be deleted after 30 days.**

Again in everyday.

```
DELETE ????
FROM Table1
WHERE  ????
```

And Table1 :

```
ID         INT
Name1      TinyInt
Name2      TinyInt
Name3      TinyInt
DateT      DateTime
```

Comment: The question is duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Comment: this is my question : " the first day data will be deleted after 30 days." And that not my answer . Please Read first and then answer(negative).

Comment: Please, If you do not, do not say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

In SQL Server Agent,

```
DELETE FROM table1
      WHERE DateT > dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) and DateT < dateadd(day, -29, getdate())
```

Comment: Just be careful about the time component here. What datatype is DateT? Does it have a time component?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Type is 'DateTime'.