# How to move record from one server to another server in a efficient way on daily basis?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linq, stored-procedures

I want to move the record from one server to another server on certain criteria.

**Note**

> I don't want to move all the records, I will do some filter on records that which I want
>
> I have to move the records on daily basis.
>
> That server is not in local network.

So If I make stored procedure using linq server, it is possible to move the records. But I don't think it is good way. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

what about **BCP Utility**?.

I don't have such awareness about it, Is it good performance to export and import for bulk data?

Comment: Do the following things :
1. Create Linked server
2. writer Query
Let Server1 with IP:172.16.9.13
Server1 with IP:172.16.9.14

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things :
1. Create Linked server
2. writer Query
Let Server1 with IP:172.16.9.13
Server2 with IP:172.16.9.14
You want to move data from Server1 to Server2 then first add Server2 at Server1
The Write Query Like

```
Insert into 172.16.9.14.SomeTable

    select * from 172.16.9.13.SomeTable where isactive=1
```

====================Create Linked Server =====================
http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server

Answer (score 0):

You can add linked server and create procedure for moving records as per your filter criteria.Then schedule sql job on daily basis.
 [Sample Link for Creating Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Second option:-
Please create Web service .In that service do this functionality .First fetch the data from target server and then insert to source server.Run this webservice in daily basis using timer or [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Comment: do you know anything about bcp utility to export and import bulk records?