# SQL Server DATETIME, automatically fill at exactly 10pm of the day when not fill before 10pm of the same day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table structure:

```
ID int
status varchar (10)
DATE_CREATED datetime
DATE_CLOSED datetime
```

Stored procedure for filling `DATE_CREATED`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[...]
    @ID INT,
    @STATUS VARCHAR(10) = 'Open',
    @DATE_CREATED DATETIME = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE table
    SET STATUS = @STATUS,
        DATE_CREATED = COALESCE(@DATE_CREATED, GETDATE())
    FROM table
```

From that point the column `DATE_CLOSED` is `NULL`. I wanted to automatically fill the column with the date of `DATE_CREATED` column but with the time of 10pm, and it should be filled by 10pm automatically and also the status filled to 'closed'.

Comment: "it should be filled by 10pm automatically".  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate 10 p.m. on the current date using:

```
dateadd(hour, 22, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

This is easy to add into the `update`.  I'm not 100% sure, though, that this is all you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks it worked well, lastly how will i set the other  column status to a closed at 10pm?

Comment: You can set up a SQL Server Agent job to run at 10:00 p.m. to set the status.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to schedule a query or stored procedure to run at a set time of the day, then the normal approach is to use SQL Server Agent which has fairly elaborate job scheduling functionality.

Look at this question for an example of how to run a daily job.
[how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

And here's Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job