# How to update a column based on an amount of time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure to update a column based on an amount of time. For example, to update the interest generated column every 15 days.

Here is my code. Please help.

```
create table Loan(
Loan_ID int not null primary key,
Loan_custID int not null foreign key references Customers(Cust_ID),
Loan_Amount int not null,
Loan_Interest int not null,
Loan_Date date not null unique,
)

Create table Interestgenerated(
IG_ID int not null primary key,
Loan_ID int not null foreign key references Loan1(Loan_ID),
Loan_Date date null foreign key references Loan1(Loan_Date),
IG_Amount int not null,
IG_Date datetime not null
)
create procedure InsertINtoInterestgenerated1
@PresentDate  Datetime

as
set @PresentDate=getdate()


select Loan_ID from Loan
set IG_Date=Loan_Date
IG_Date=dateadd(day,15, IG_Date)
if @PresentDate=IG_Date
begin
update Interestgenerated1 set IG_Date = @PresentDate, IG_Amount=IG_Amount*0.15
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `update the interest generated colum every 15 days.`. What will happen if somebody execute the query that updates that more than once in 15 days ? I would make a function to calculate the interest based on the base line date and current date

Comment: I want it to do that automatically so it won't depend on nobody, It will only depend on the Loan_date. I mean every  15 days after the Loan date it automatically generate the interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you want to automate the update of the value in column IG_Amount every 15 days,
you can schedule a job to run every 15 days at midnight like on the 1st and 16th of every month.

the below link might help you:

[how to schedule a job for sql query to run daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Comment: every 15 days ? It will work provide all records have the same base line date

Comment: @AmeyaN99 That will work but I want it to do that based on the Loan_date. I mean to start based on the loan date.

Comment: so i think in update condition u need to check if the IG_Date and systemdate(the date when job is running) is equal to 15