# SQL Set a dummy date of Today at 5AM

Tags: sql-server, datetime, getdate

I have a table that shows Date, Area, and Qty. The dates are all null, but I want to set a dummy date/time of today at 5am for all values in the table. I want the date portion to change to today based on whatever today's date is. But, I ant the hour portion to always be 5am.

```
Date Area Qty
Null A    1
Null B    3
Null C    2
```

So today, november 5th, the Date field of every record would show

```
2018-11-05 05:00:00.000
```

If the record is still there tomorrow, November 6th, it would change to

```
2018-11-06 05:00:00.000
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you OK with a `SELECT` statement that retrieves the fake date for that column? Or do you want to actually store that value in the table?  If storing in the table maybe a job that runs nightly and updates the date column.  Otherwise you can probably do something like `select '2018-11-05 05:00:00.000' as date, area, qty from MyTable;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this just to show, or with a job to update the table every day:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HH, 5, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET [Date] = (SELECT 
                   CAST(CAST(GetDate() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + 
                   CAST('05:00:00' AS DATETIME)
             );
```

If you need to do this every day, you can [schedule a job](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471080/6426692) to run this query every day.

Answer (score 0):

Just add + 1 to the existing date and it will increment by 1 day

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET [Date] = [Date] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that column to a calculated column (that is what you are describing after all):

```
alter table myTable drop column [Date];
alter table myTable add [Date] as 
  cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + 
  cast('05:00 AM' as datetime);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c736662ca9953a09ae2b828f9e91cae8)