# SQL Server automatically start routine

Tags: sql-server, routines

The title pretty much says it all: I want to automatically start a routine in MS SQL Server. More precisely, I have a routine (which deletes data from a table on a certain condition) that is supposed to run everyday, but I don't want to have an application having to trigger this routine.

Is there a functionality in SQL Server which supports this behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: It's called a [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/agent/create-jobs).

Comment: Look at into the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily