# Scheduled Transfer data from DB To DB in SQL express edition 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have an requirement in order to transfer information from Table_1 in Database Test_1 to Table_2 in Database Test_2

Also these information should be in schedule Transfer with specific time(Ex: 11am)

I am using MS SQL 2014 Express edition.

New to SQL, So kindly guide me through in order to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily) is what you would use to *schedule* this transfer at 1100, but it is not included with SQL Server Express. You can read more on what features are included and not included [here, in the MS Documents.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017)

Since you can't use SQL Agent, you will have to use another scheduling mechanism like a PowerShell Script, Batch Script, etc that's triggered via Windows Scheduler or a Cron Job or whatever with the [sqlcmd utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

> The sqlcmd utility lets you enter Transact-SQL statements, system
>   procedures, and script files through a variety of available modes:
>
> - At the command prompt.
> - In Query Editor in SQLCMD mode.
> - In a Windows script file.
> - In an operating system (Cmd.exe) job step of a SQL Server Agent job.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point to get some ideas of how it can be done:

Step 1: create a stored procedure that will perform a table copy:

```
USE yourDB
GO
CREATE PROC uspCopyTable
AS
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table_2') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Table_2

SELECT * INTO dbo.Table_2 FROM dbo.Table_1
```

Step 2: schedule the execution of the stored procedure using Windows Task Scheduler:

```
sqlcmd.exe -Q "EXEC dbo.uspCopyTable" -o "C:\Temp\MyOutput.txt" -d "yourDB"
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response..can you explain the second step in detail.. Should I run this command in cmd or copy this command in notepad & save it as Bat file

Comment: Is it possible to set a flag or any identification for the data's that are imported from Table_1?

Comment: I would rather advise using a bat file. Regarding identification of the data, it can be achieved perhaps by adding extra column like `[SourceTable]`. For example:  `SELECT *, 'Table_1' AS SourceTable INTO dbo.Table_2 FROM dbo.Table_1`

Comment: If I add an extra column like you said... How to update that column.. When I am importing or transferring data from Table_1 to Table_2... Also.. To create bat file... What command shou I give...

Comment: In a snippet I posted above, the column is already prefilled with value 'Table_1'. Regarding bat file, if it will be executed locally, you can literally copy paste the code from my answer