# Make table automatically update row

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a database with the following columns:

```
CurrentCredits, CreditsPerDate, RefillDate, RefillFrequency, RefillDayMonth
```

I'd like to make it automatically update the `CreditsPerDate` and `RefillDate` depending on the frequency selected.

For example,

```
if RefillFrequency = 5 and RefillDayMonth = "day" and CreditsPerMonth = 2
```

I want it to update `CurrentCredits` and `RefillDate` every 5 days such that

```
CurrentCredits = CurrentCredits + CreditsPerMonth and 
RefillDate = RefillDate + the frequency date (here add 5 days)
```

Comment: Have a look at [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a SQL job?. Here you have an example: [how to schedule a job for sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-to-schedule-a-job-for-sql-query-to-run-daily)

Inside your job you can create a update or command with stored procedure like

```
exec (your stored procedure name) (and possibly add parameters)
```

just updating your parameters and values.

Let us know if this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a table to do that by itself. I would say go with Patricio's idea and schedule a job to run. Write a stored proc and have that run daily to run calculations. You will need additional columns probably to help facilitate this as you will need to know when a row was last updated and use that date (ie, UpdateDt) to determine if some values will need to be recalculated.