# Simple solution to provide CSV from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, export-to-csv

I have a user that needs a CSV from SQL Server once or twice each month. I have been running the query and then exporting the CSV to a network location manually, but I want to automate this so that they can pull the data on their own or have it scheduled to update the file every other week.

It has been a long time since providing a solution like this, and I am overthinking it, so I am looking for a suggestion on what would be the proper way to provide a file like this now.

I currently just have a database connection setup in Excel that will run the query when the user wants it, but this feels unprofessional to provide as a solution.

Thanks for any recommendations.

Comment: You can use data export wizard to create an SSIS package and run it via a scheduled SQL Job. You can also run @david-browne-microsoft script via Scheduled Task.

Comment: SSRS...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\david> invoke-sqlcmd "select * from sys.objects" | export-csv -Path "c:\temp\data.csv"
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471080/how-can-i-schedule-a-job-to-run-a-sql-query-daily